# jquery & ajax response to get values of the php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm beginner to use jquery and Ajax functions.

I make a website with a table with multiple rows, this rows loaded from database with php. Now when I click to edit button show the info of this fields. To get it, I have read the best way is use ajax.

In this jquery code, the idea is loop every cells and when the cell is codigo exit loop each and set this value at the post method of the ajax function.

My code:

```
        $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

            var $button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            var row = $button.closest("tr"), // edit button is in the same row as data you want to change
            $tds = row.find("td"); // get all table cells in that row
            var cod;

            $.each($tds, function(index,value) {

                var field = $(this).data("field");

                if (field == 'codigo'){
                    cod = $(this).text();
                    return false;   
                }
            });

            alert(cod);

            $.ajax({ 
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'queryProduct.php',
                data: {codigo: cod}

            }).done(function(response){
                response = JSON.parse(response);

                // Here get the values of the JSON      

            });

            var src_value = $tds.closest("td").find('img').attr('src');         // Get attrib src de img and set to a modal window element
            $('[name="imagen"]').attr("src",src_value);

        });
```

queryProduct.php

```
<?php   
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] <> ''){

                include("functions.php"); 
                include("tools.php"); 

                $conn = Conectarse("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");  

                $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];

                echo $codigo;

                $query = "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_producto WHERE codigo={$codigo}"; 

                $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  

                if ($result == TRUE) {
                    echo json_encode($result);
                } else {
                    echo "Error query: " . $conn->error;
                }

                $conn->close();

        } else{
            ?><p>La sesión no está activa, por favor ingrese <a href="login.php">aquí</a></p>
<?php   
        }?>
```

The problem is from the developer console show me an error message in the queryProduct.php I do not sure the problem is sending the code variable to method post :(

Show error message from developer console:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove the quotes in `data: {codigo: "$(this).text()"}`

Comment: @Andreas I have removed it but there is any more... with console.log doesn't show the codigo value. How do I to get codigo value? I updated my code with the HTML code with the data-fields.

Comment: @Andreas I updated my code. The problem with the value of the code data-field is solved. The problem is when I post this value always the console shows me an error message.

Comment: Add the error message to your post so we can see what happen.

Comment: I am trying to open this URL which diplay in console. Its not working https://addcom-web-developer/addcloud/queryProduct.php

Comment: It is not public, it's an intranet web site.

Comment: Is it working for you properly when you run direct in browser ?

Comment: No, the same error.

Comment: is that URL  http://addcom-web-developer/addcloud/queryProduct.php  working for you. ? Try run directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the pg commands of php.

Normally I used mysql database and in my code was a mysql commands.

Now it's working:

```
            if (!$result) {
                echo "Error query: " . pg_last_error($conn);
            } else {
                echo json_encode($result);
            }

            pg_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your data into this:

```
 data: {codigo: cod}. // since your cod is already a variable
```

Comment: Also I have tried with you but it's not works! I have updated the code with your changes.

Comment: after you alert(cod); does it alert something? does the cod had a value?

Comment: if there is no error regarding the url in your ajax, try this on your queyproduct. if(isset($_post)) { var_dump($_post); } put this before your isset(session) condition

Comment: What is it mean this code? I have put in the queryProduct.php at line 1 before that the isset(session) but I do not see change

Comment: When I open the Developer Window from browser show this message: 'Internal Server Error 500"

Comment: does 'internal server error 500' occur before you modify your code?

Comment: it means there's something wrong on your queryProduct.php

Comment: "if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] <> ''){" change to 

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] <> ''){

Comment: I have changed it but it's the same error. This line: if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] <> ''){ it's working fine in others pages of my web site. I am going to change the queryProduct.php, only a line: echo "Hello";...

Comment: Only with echo "Hello" it's working fine, that the problem is the queryProduct.php I have deleted the first condition if(isset($...) but the error message it's the same. I have updated my question with a screenshot with the error message.

Comment: go to dev tools, and go to network, then click the error. the error will display there. i mean the xhr that has the error

Comment: can you screen shot also the response and the preview

Comment: What response and what preview? Sorry I do not understand it

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question with this screenshots.

Comment: as you can see the value of cod is 38, then the error i think is now on your sql statement if i am not wrong

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_producto WHERE codigo={$codigo}";

change to 

 "SELECT * FROM ma_producto WHERE codigo={$codigo}"; or
 "SELECT * FROM ma_producto WHERE codigo= '".$codigo."'" ;

Comment: I think that it's not the problem. This query is working fine. Before that I recovered the values of the fields using jquery then now I want to retrieve the values using ajax.

Comment: The problem is this line: `if ($result == True) {` on the queryProduct.php I'm going to find an alternative.

Comment: ok you can use this if($result) { // your code } else { // other code }, and goodluck hope it helps you